# Confusion about declaring pointers to id

Tags: objective-c, class, object, pointers, struct

Please consider these 2 code statements:

```
id class1 = [[MyClass alloc]init]; //First 
MyClass * class2 = [[MyClass alloc]init]; //Second
```

`class1` and `class2` are pointers to type `id` right? In a header file of `objc`, I saw that `Class` is just typedef of a struct pointer, and `id` is typedef of a struct pointer as well. With those types being declared as pointers to struct, why do I need to include a `*` in the second statement of my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `id` is a type. It can hold a pointer to any object.
- `Class` is a type. It can hold a pointer to any class object. (A class object is the object representing a class. i.e. the object that gets messaged when you call a class (`+`) method.)
- `MyClass *` is a type. It can hold a pointer to any object that is an instance of `MyClass`

`class1` and `class2` are pointers to objects.

You seem to have some big confusion between class objects and instances of classes. A `MyClass *` is a pointer to a `MyClass` instance, i.e. an object whose class is `MyClass`. That is completely different from the *class object* representing the `MyClass` class itself. The `MyClass` class object is not an instance of `MyClass`. Class objects are a more advanced topic that you should probably not think about now.

Comment: I think this is a confusing topic in general. There's also the bit about knowing what's runtime and compile-time, which seems related.

Comment: @newact: If you say that `MyClass *` is a type then it would be like, `aStruct * *` right? If I am right, could you please explain what it means, cause I think that this is the one last thing that confuses me. Thanks.

Comment: @user007: `MyClass` is not a legal type in Objective-C, but if it were legal, it would be a struct type, just like class types in C++. So `MyClass *` is the type of a pointer to some struct. I think your confusion comes from the fact that there's a type named `Class` that is an object pointer type, and you somehow think that anywhere you see the name of a class (e.g. `MyClass`), that you can replace it with `Class`. But it's nothing like that. "`Class`" is simply the name of a special type in Objective-C. It has nothing to do with the type of instances of some class (e.g. `MyClass`).

Answer (score 1):

Because `id` a pointer to `struct` already:

```
typedef struct objc_object {
    Class isa;
} *id;
```

Where as `MyClass` isn't a pointer.

Comment: But classes are of type `Class`, `Class` is pointer to `struct`.

Comment: @user007 No they're not; `Class` describes the class from which instances are created.  `MyClass *` points to an instance of a class.

Comment: So you mean that classes are of type `struct`? So how do classes fit in the argument of `objc_msgSend` which requires a type `id`?

Comment: @user007 Because if `id` is `struct *` then `objc_msgSend()` simply accepts a pointer to the `struct` (which is how you'd normally pass `structs` to functions).

Comment: how about for classes. How can you pass pointer to structs if they aren't pointer to struct?

Comment: @trojanfoe: `Class` is indeed a type that can hold pointers to class objects

Comment: @user007: A pointer to a class object can be held in a variable of type `Class`, just like a pointer to any object can be held in a variable of type `id`. How is that relevant?